# What is length issues of the array_splice in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am a beginner in php. I am trying to understand about the array_splice(). I did not get about the length argument. If the it is positive or negative then I can not understand how the returned array is formed. Please describe me how this is treating with this `array_splice()` function in php.

```
 $input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
 array_splice($input, 1, -1);
 // $input is now array("red", "yellow")
```

How this is happening? Please help me to understand this.

Comment: You are right, sorry. (green, blue) is the result of `array_splice`, then the array now is red - yellow. array_splice remove elements from position 1 to -1)

Comment: Have you tried [RTFM](http://php.net/array_splice)? Is [the description of the `length` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#refsect1-function.array-splice-parameters) there not understandable? What don't you understand about it?

Comment: In this exact example - `array_splice($input, 1, -1);` is the same as `array_splice($input, 1, count($input)-1);` or `array_splice($input, 1, 2);`. Using a `-1` allows you to remove everything up to, but not including, the last element, without having to know how many elements are there.

Comment: The problem is to understand how the negative values in the arguments is working.. this is confusing to me..(though this simple matter). @deceze

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of array_splice used here is

array_splice(arg1,arg2,arg3)

arg1 - Passed array

arg2 - Starting position of the array. 0 refers to the first element, 1 as the second element.. and so on.

arg3 - Specifies how many elements will be removed, and also length of the returned array. If this value is set to a negative number, the function will stop that far from the last element.

Thus, in your code, the starting position is 1 i.e the second element "green".
And the last argument is -1 i.e the second last position "blue".

Therefore, it removes the values "green" and "blue" and you're left with array("red", "yellow").

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: That is great.. But I did not get how the negative values treating to return the new array. Please explain in easy way, not as in php.net.

Comment: The negative value means you're discarding a value from the end. If it's -2, it means you are discarding two values from the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It did well.